# gVim opening a tab pushes status line out of window

Tags: window-manager, gvim

When opening a new tab in gVim (with `:tabe`), the status line at the bottom of the screen disappears.  If I press `:` and start typing a command I can no longer see the command on the status line.

When the gVim window is maximized, opening a tab pushes the status line below the screen.  When the gVim window is not maximized, the window will increase in height.  This problem happens in Gnome and in Xmonad.

I'm looking for a way to get around this issue.  Is there a way to force the window to redraw such that the status line fits inside the window?

Comment: This behaviour happens to me as well, using gVim 7.3 and KDE 4.4+. I've tried three different fixes for it:

1) Patch, recompile: http://paskov.biz/blog/patch-for-properly-maximizingresizing-gvim-under-kde-4-x-kwin/
2) Screw with KDE's "Application Specific" settings. This sorta-kinda-works, but isn't reliable.
3) Switch to Qtk-gVim. This doesn't really fix it either, although it does maximize properly. 

The problem is highly frustrating, even if de-maximize+maximize fixes it.

Comment: it happens too on nvim (neovim) 0.3.8 under KDE, in nvim-qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me as well. The workaround that I use is to minimize gVim then maximize it again. After that the status bar is visible again.
Bug is described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/137854
Bug is reported fixed in debian, but the issue is still there with Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty)

Comment: I use the same workaround to resolve the bug.  Thanks for the bug link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem only seems to come up when the tab line first gets displayed.  The workaround I use is just to always show the tabline:

```
:set showtabline=2
```

(in .vimrc of course).  I personally don't mind having the extra line there when I just have one tab open, so it works for me, anyway.

Comment: This is the best workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Vim 7.3, using the [Vim 7.3 PPA for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~passy/+archive/vim) mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/7284).  Unfortunately this still did not solve the problem.

My current workaround involves using no-gui tab pages instead.  I removed the GUI tab pages by removing `e` from `guioptions` in my .vimrc file, like so:

```
set guioptions-=e
```